# Is there any scene in Naruto where anbu commits suicide?

Tags: naruto

I cant find but Im sure there was a scene where Kabuto chases an Anbu and that Anbu commits suicide or something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably thinking of the [Body Elimination Technique](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Body_Elimination_Technique), which makes it debut in filler episode [A Shinobi's Determination](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/A_Shinobi%27s_Determination)

> An Anbu member seemingly manages to locate the general area of Orochimaru's hideout and sends a message to Konoha to notify Tsunade, before eliminating all traces of his body